# explain notifier.c from the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, inotify

I'm seeking to fully understand the following code snippet from kernel/notifier.c. I have read and built simple link lists and think I get the construct from K&R's C programming. However this is slightly more complex. The second line below which begins with the 'int' appears to be two items together which is unclear. 
The first is the (*notifier_call) which I believe has independent but related significance with the second containing a 'notifier block' term.

Can you explain how it works in detail? I understand that there is a function pointer and multiple subscribers possible. But I lack the way to tie these facts together, and could use a primer or key so I exactly understand how the code works. The third line looks to contain the linking structure, or recursive nature. Forgive my terms, and correct them as fit as I am a new student of computer science terminology.

```
    struct notifier_block {
        int (*notifier_call)(struct notifier_block *, unsigned long, void *);
        struct notifier_block *next;
        int priority;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple pointer to a function returning int, taking as its arguments a pointer to a `notifier_block` structure, an unsigned long, and a pointer to void.

It has nothing to do with the linked list, that is linked by the `next` member.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why is the int format 'int ()();'? Does this signify dimensionality? I am only aware of the int format 'int n;'.

Comment: This is well described in any C or C++ reference.  The first parentheses bind the `*` to the name. Without it the `*` would bind to the `int`, making it a function (not a pointer to a function) returning `int *`, which would be an error as you can't define a function inside a `struct` in C.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unclear as to why int has two items after it without a comma between them. Its a structure of some sort but I do not know its name and attempt to locate it are unresolved. For example 'int a,b;' declares two variables, but what does 'int ab;' do?